# Prove $\models_{S_5}\square(\square P\to\square Q)\lor\square(\square Q\to \square P)$ with natural deduction

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, modal-logic

> Some defs. in general:
>
> Let $\mathscr{M}(=\left<\mathscr{W,R,I~}\right>)$ be some MPL-model,
>
> Where $\mathscr{W}$ is a non-empty set of objects **("possible worlds")**
>
> $\mathscr{R}$ is a binary relation over $\mathscr{W}$ **("accessiblity relation")**
>
> $\mathscr{I}$ is a two-place function **("interpretation function")**
>
> that assigns $0$ or $1$ to each $\underline{\text{sentence}}$ $\alpha$ relative to each world $\omega\in\mathscr{W}$
>
> $V_\mathscr{M}$ is a two-place function **("valuation function")**
>
> that assigns $0$ or $1$ to each $\underline{\text{wffs}}$ $\phi$ relative to each world $\omega\in\mathscr{W}$
>
> Let $V_\mathscr{M}$ be the valuation for $\mathscr{M}$, $\alpha$ be some sentence letter and $\omega\in\mathscr{W}$, then we have
>
> $$V_\mathscr{M}(\alpha,\omega)=\mathscr{I(\alpha,\omega)}\tag*{(1)}$$
>
> $$V_\mathscr{M}(\neg\phi,\omega)=1\text{ iff }V_\mathscr{M}(\phi,\omega)=0\tag*{(2)}$$
>
> $$V_\mathscr{M}(\phi\to\varphi,\omega)=1\text{ iff }V_\mathscr{M}(\phi,\omega)=0\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(\varphi,v)=1\tag*{(3)}$$
>
> $$V_\mathscr{M}(\square\phi,\omega)=1\text{ iff }~\forall v\in\mathscr{W},\mathscr{R}wv\to V_{\mathscr{M}}(\phi,v)=1\tag*{(4)}$$
>
> $$\text{etc.}$$

Prove the following statement

$$\models_{S_5}\square(\square P\to\square Q)\lor\square(\square Q\to \square P)$$

The question is asking to prove the statement in [$S_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_(modal_logic)), and i'm not familiar with natural deduction in MPL, but here my thoughts:

$1.$ Apply $(4)$
$$V_\mathscr{M}(\square(\square P\to\square Q)\lor\square(\square Q\to \square P),\omega)=1$$
$$\text{ iff }~\forall v_1\in\mathscr{W},\mathscr{R}wv_1\to \color{blue}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square P\to\square Q,v_1)=1}\lor \color{red}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square Q\to\square P,v_1)=1}\tag*{(0)}$$
$2.1.$ Apply $(3)$
$$\color{blue}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square P\to\square Q,v_1)=1}$$
$$\text{ iff }~\forall v_2\in\mathscr{W},(\mathscr{R}v_1v_2\to V_{\mathscr{M}}(P,v_2)=0\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(Q,v_2)=1)$$
$2.2.$ Apply $(3)$
$$\color{red}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square Q\to\square P,v_1)=1}$$
$$\text{ iff }~\forall v_2\in\mathscr{W},(\mathscr{R}v_1v_2\to V_{\mathscr{M}}(Q,v_2)=0\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(P,v_2)=1)$$
$3.$ put $2.1$ and $2.2$ together
$$\color{blue}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square P\to\square Q,v_1)=1}\lor \color{red}{V_{\mathscr{M}}(\square Q\to\square P,v_1)=1}$$
$$\text{ iff }~\forall v_2\in\mathscr{W},(\mathscr{R}v_1v_2$$
$$\to \underbrace{V_{\mathscr{M}}(P,v_2)=0\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(Q,v_2)=1\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(Q,v_2)=0\lor V_{\mathscr{M}}(P,v_2)=1)}_{\text{tautology}}$$

$4.$ Substitute this tautology back to $(0)$ we get:

$$\forall v_1\in\mathscr{W}\big(\mathscr{R}wv_1\to(\forall v_2\in\mathscr{W},(\mathscr{R}v_1v_2\to\top))\big)$$

Which is also a tautology, hence proved.

---

Is this analysis correct $?$

Please tell me if there is any mistakes.

And how do I prove this with natural deduction $?$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\square(\square P\to \square Q)$ does not hold at some world, there is a world in its equivalence class where $\square P\to\square Q$ fails, so in particular, $\square Q$ fails, and hence $Q$ fails somewhere in the equivalence class of worlds. Thus $\square Q$ is fails everywhere in the equivalence class and so $\square Q\to \square P$ holds everywhere in the class, and so $\square(\square Q\to\square P)$ holds at the original world.

Comment: I don’t believe you need to use natural deduction or that this has anything to do with natural deduction or formal deduction in general. The question is nominally about validity in terms of Kripke semantics, as are all the definitions you provided. The imperative “prove” is meant in the informal sense. (Though by soundness, producing a formal proof from the S5 axioms would certainly establish the results.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Thank you, I see, and what you think about my proof, is the idea correct $?$

Comment: I haven’t followed (which I think says more about the amount of time and attention span I have right now than how well you’ve expressed yourself) but one thing that jumps out at me is that you don’t seem to have used the S5 frame condition but this isn’t valid in arbitrary frames.

Comment: Looking into it, it looks like pretty much every step is wrong due to scoping errors. For instance in 1. The statement means that for every accessible world, $\square P\to\square Q$ holds or for every accessible world $\square Q\to\square P$ holds. Not that for every accessible world $\square P\to\square Q$ or $\square Q\to\square P$ holds. The former is a much stronger statement than the latter.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ah$\dots$yes thats the mistake, the quantifier $\forall$ can only distribute out when it connect with  $\lor$ but not distribute in, I forgot that, Thanks!